# Missing Storyboard in Xcode

Tags: storyboard, xcode5

I have read other posts on this topic. But it is not working for me. I can't find my storyboard in the project. I am sure that the storyboard still exist, because when i launch my app on my phone, there is no problem. I have checked in all folders of my app if it is there.. I also checked my trash.. But no sucsses. Any idea?

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0):

try Command+space and type storyboard. if it exists in the app, it should show up in the result.

Comment: I couldn't find it anymore.. had to do it all over again.. Still don't know what was the problem. Is there a chance to get autosave files somewhere in Xcode?